When I try to run test case with embedded pg in spring boot it showing me below error
Process [/var/folders/z5/8c_cdt8s7y9b6_mvqs2v7p3m0000gp/T/embedded-pg/PG-0c0585587b40695247cf72650cd42f92/bin/initdb, -A, trust, -U, postgres, -D, /var/folders/z5/8c_cdt8s7y9b6_mvqs2v7p3m0000gp/T/epg3260060667162991560, -E, UTF-8] failedjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Process [/var/folders/z5/8c_cdt8s7y9b6_mvqs2v7p3m0000gp/T/embedded-pg/PG-0c0585587b40695247cf72650cd42f92/bin/initdb, -A, trust, -U, postgres, -D, /var/folders/z5/8c_cdt8s7y9b6_mvqs2v7p3m0000gp/T/epg3260060667162991560, -E, UTF-8] failedat io.zonky.test.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres.system(EmbeddedPostgres.java:632)
I have verified with testcases, but there is no problem with that. It running fine before....
Here is my sample code
import com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class EmbeddedPostgresTest {

    private static EmbeddedPostgres embeddedPostgres;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void startEmbeddedPostgres() throws IOException {
        // Start embedded PostgreSQL instance
        embeddedPostgres = EmbeddedPostgres.builder().start();
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", embeddedPostgres.getJdbcUrl("postgres", "postgres"));
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", "postgres");
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", "");
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void stopEmbeddedPostgres() throws IOException {
        // Stop the embedded PostgreSQL instance
        if (embeddedPostgres != null) {
            embeddedPostgres.close();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testDatabaseConnection() {
        // Test your repository/database interaction
        jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE test(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100));");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('TestName');");

        Integer count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test", Integer.class);
        assertThat(count).isEqualTo(1);
    }
}


On what Operating System and Platform are you running?

I am running on mac os

11+? Big sur look up "failedjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Process macos" there are a lot of similar issues
